# Find $f(X)$ that minimizes $E[(Y-f(X))^2|X]$

Tags: probability, statistics, derivatives, expectation

> Let $X$ and $Y$ random variables with $E(Y)=\mu$ and $E(Y^2)<\infty$.
>   Deduce that the random variable $f(X)$ that minimizes
>   $E[(Y-f(X))^2|X]$ is $f(X)=E[Y|X]$.

I just find the minimum with derivatives

$$\frac{d}{d f(X)}E[(Y-f(X))^2|X]=-2E[Y-f(X)|X]$$

$$=-2E[Y|X]+2E[f(X)|X]=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow E[Y|X]=E[f(X)|X]$$
$$\Leftrightarrow f(X)=E[Y|X]$$

Is this right?

I founded this solution

[image]

Is this wrong too?

Comment: This is very far from being right. First problem is, what does that even mean to minimize a random variable, namely, the random variable $E((Y-f(X))^2\mid X)$? Next, your use of derivative is.... well, let us say, innovative.

Comment: @Did I don't know what is a random variable that minimizes a expectation. I just take it from the book [Time series and forecasting](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Forecasting-Springer-Texts-Statistics/dp/0387953515/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1473082130&sr=8-1&keywords=introduction+to+time+series+and+forecasting)

Comment: @Did I wouldn't call it so wrong, nor innovative. It makes sense if one minimizes the square for a given (fixed) value of $X$ - in that case it's the direct generalization of showing that the value of $a$ that minimizes $E([X - a]^2)$ is $a=E(X)$.

Comment: @leonbloy What is $\frac{\partial}{\partial f(X)}$ already? You see. It seems that, despite your good heart, I will stick to "very far from being right"...

Comment: See eg http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-011-introduction-to-communication-control-and-signal-processing-spring-2010/readings/MIT6_011S10_chap08.pdf

Comment: @PRAGAKHAM $\frac{d}{df(X)}$ is equally problematic.

Comment: @Did I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: @PRAGAKHAM "What is wrong" is that there exists no canonical definition of $$\frac{\partial}{\partial W}E(Z\mid X)$$ for some given random variables $(X,Z,W)$. So, if you are referring to the notion, you should explain what you mean by it.

Comment: @Did Can you see the solution that I founded?

Comment: @PRAGAKHAM Yeah, the solution that you reproduced follows the standard approach. Look carefully at the derivatives that are considered there, and how they differ from the one you suggest in your question.

Comment: @Did $\frac{d}{df(X)}E[Y^2|X]$ is 0? In this case is there a canonical definition? I really don't understand why it's is right.

Comment: @PRAGAKHAM Sorry but did you read even only ONE of my comments? How would you DEFINE $\frac{d}{df(X)}E(Y^2\mid X)$?

Comment: @Did I read all your comments. You said to look carefully at the derivatives in the solution that I founded. From your comment about canonical definition, I think that does not exist in this case. I don't understood what you meant by "Yeah, the solution that you reproduced follows the standard approach. Look carefully at the derivatives that are considered there". You mean that the second solution I found is correct? Why? What difference in derivatives?

Comment: @PRAGAKHAM When I see $\frac{d}{dc}E((Y-c)^2)$, I understand what it means because $E((Y-c)^2)$ is a number depending on $c$, say $E((Y-c)^2)=g(c)$ hence I have a function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and the author means $g'(c)$. Nothing of this is left when I see $\frac{d}{df(X)}E((Y-f(X))^2\mid X)$. This can mean one of two things only: either I missed something, or the author does not know what what they write even mean. So, for the sixth time: How. Do. You. Define. $\frac{d}{df(X)}E((Y-f(X))^2\mid X)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try to make your argument more rigorously legitimate. First, let's agree that the goal is to find some (measurable) function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for any (measurable) function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ the inequality
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[(Y- f(X))^2 \mid X\right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[(Y - g(X))^2 \mid X\right] \tag{1}
$$
holds almost surely. Now, let $\Omega$ be the sample space on which $X$ is defined and let $h(X) : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a representative of $\mathbb{E}\left[Y \mid X\right]$ and $k(X)$ be a representative of $\mathbb{E}\left[ Y^2 \mid X \right]$, each defined for every $\omega \in \Omega$. Then, 
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[(Y-f(X))^2 \mid X\right] = k(X) - 2 f(X) h(X) + f(X)^2
$$
(where equality means the RHS is in the equivalence class of the LHS). Now, for a fixed $\omega \in \Omega$, if we minimize
$$
k(X)(\omega) - 2 \lambda h(X)(\omega) + \lambda^2
$$
in the variable $\lambda$, using differentiation as you have above, you will find that $\lambda = h(X)(\omega)$. Thus, for each $\omega \in \Omega$, defining $\lambda(\omega) = h(X)(\omega)$ minimizes the previous expression pointwise in $\Omega$. Thus with $f(X) = h(X)$, Eq. $(1)$ is minimized almost surely.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: the typical trick is the minus-and-add trick: with $Z=E(Y|X)$,
\begin{aligned}
E[(Y-f(X))^2|X]&=E[(Y-Z+Z-f(X))^2|X]\\
&=E[(Y-Z)^2|X]+2E[(Y-Z)(Z-f(X))|X]+E[(Z-f(X))^2|X].
\end{aligned}
Now note that
$$
E[(Y-Z)(Z-f(X))|X]=(Z-f(X))\underbrace{E[Y-Z|X]}_0=0.
$$
What now can you infer about $E[(Y-f(X))^2|X]$ and $E[(Y-Z)^2|X]$?