# Find $arg \min_{f} \mathbb{E}_{xy}(y - f(x))^2$ where x, y are random variable

Tags: probability-theory, derivatives, random-variables, expected-value

$x, y : \mathbb{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ - are random variable

I need to find function f, that minimize $\mathbb{E}_{xy}(y - f(x))^2 $ - mathematical expectation of the joint density of random variables x, y.

My solution is

$$(\mathbb{E}_{xy} y^2 - 2\mathbb{E}_{xy}yf(x) + \mathbb{E}_{xy}f^2(x))|_{f}' = $$
$$ = ( \mathbb{E}_{xy} y^2 - 2 \mathbb{E}_{x} \left[ \mathbb{E} (yf(x) | x) \right] + \mathbb{E}_{x} \left[ \mathbb{E} (f^2(x) | x) \right])|_{f}'= $$
$$=\left|f(x) \ is \ x-measurable \right| = $$
$$= (-2 \mathbb{E}_x(f(x) \mathbb{E}(y | x)) + \mathbb{E}_{x} \left[ f^2(x) \right])|_{f}'=  $$
$$  = (-2 \mathbb{E}_x(f(x) \mathbb{E}(y | x)) + \mathbb{E}_{x} \left[ f^2(x) \right])|_{f}'= $$
$$ = \mathbb{E}_x \left[ (-2f(x)\mathbb{E(y |x)} +f^2(x))|_f' \right] =  $$
$$  = \mathbb{E}_x \left[ -2\mathbb{E(y |x)} + 2f(x) \right] = 0 \ (a.e.) $$
$$\Rightarrow f(x) = \mathbb{E}(y |x)$$

But i'm not sure if it is possible to differentiate by function like that. Please tell me am i right?

Comment: Have you thought of some simple cases, like $x$ Bernoulli? Say $x$ is Bernoulli. Then $x = 0$ or $x = 1,$ and you will essentially break up $\mathbf{X}$ (your sample space) into two parts (where $x = 0$ and where $x = 1$) and then you have to minimise $E_y(y - c)^2$ where now $c = f(0)$ or $c = f(1)$ is a constant. This is given (I belive) when $c = \mu_y.$ If $x$ is discrete, the result extends readily and when $x$ is not discrete, you can approximate by a discrete sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to differentiate anything. Just add and subtract $\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]$, i.e., for any $f$ s.t. the expectation exists,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[y-f(x)]^2&=\mathsf{E}[y-\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]+\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]-f(x)]^2 \\
&=\mathsf{E}[y-\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]]^2+\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]-f(x)]^2 \\
&\quad+2\mathsf{E}[(y-\mathsf{E}[y\mid x])(\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]-f(x))] \\
&=\mathsf{E}[y-\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]]^2+\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]-f(x)]^2 \\
&\ge \mathsf{E}[y-\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]]^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much for such a simple and beautiful solution. But I knew him and I would like to test my alternative solution.

Comment: @GThompson Then maybe look at [functional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative).

Comment: I think you mean to write $E[(y-f(x))^2]$. What you wrote is usually parsed as $(E[y-f(x)])^2$, for example in $\text{Var} Z=E[Z^2]-E[Z]^2$.

Comment: Could you please explain why $2\mathsf{E}[(y-\mathsf{E}[y\mid x])(\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]-f(x))] $ is equal to zero? Is it the same argument as yurnero's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1915328/808513  Why is $(\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]-f(x))$ is a constant? $x$ is a random variable , so $f(x)$ shouldn't be a constant, right?

Comment: @Nachiket Use the law of iterated expectations:
\begin{align}
&\mathsf{E}[(y-\mathsf{E}[y\mid x])(\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]-f(x))] \\
&\qquad=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[y-\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]\mid x](\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]-f(x))] \\
&\qquad= \mathsf{E}[0\times(\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]-f(x))].
\end{align}

Comment: Very sorry, still don't get it. I'm quite new to expectations. You're saying, $y-\mathsf{E}[y \mid x ] = \mathsf{E}[(y-\mathsf{E}[y\mid x]) \mid x ]$. The law of iterated expectations as I understand it is  $\mathsf{E}[X]=\mathsf{E}[E[X\mid Y]]$, which doesn't seem to be applicable to this case.

If you could point me to a good reference, I would be grateful